# using class from different directory

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

[Python 3.5.2, Docker container]

I have a class BCM in a file called metrics.py which I would like to use in several Jupyter notebooks which are in different directories.  When they are in the same file, the following obviously works `from metrics import BCM`.  I would like it to work with the following directory structure.

```
experiments\
    common\
        __init__.py
        metrics.py
    exp1\
        glm.ipynb
    exp2\
        gbm.ipynb
```

It works if I do the following

```
import os, sys

module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)

from common.metrics import BCM
```

Based on posts that I have seen here, it would seem that the following should work `from ..common.metrics import BCM`.  I get the following error `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`.

Is there a way to use that class without changing the path as shown above?